# Define custom frame of UIViewController or UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I’m doing a game in Swift 2.0 & iOS >= 8 in which I have the initial VC hosting the SKScene that manages the game itself.

When the player wins or loses, I want to show a message as below :

[image]

I show this message through another VC loaded from the interface builder with the below code called from the initial VC class :

```
let VCWin = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WinVC") as! WinVC
VCWin.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
VCWin.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(VCWin, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It is important that WinVC allows to see what is behind dimmed as FormSheet & CrossDissolve properties enable to do.

WinVC will also host a view that presents a SKScene which does some sprite animations.

My problem is to remove the white parts near the rounded yellow corners in order to see what is behind (like the rest of the screen that is dimmed).

Is it possible to set the frame of a VC to the mask of the image used here ? or to set the frame of a view to the mask of the image used and have the VC below transparent ?

I have removed everything from WinVC to avoid having issues caused by other parts of the code

```
class WinVC: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        for _ in touches
        {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
    }
}
```

Also the setup in the interface builder :

VC Setup

[image]

view Setup

[image]

Image Setup

[image]

Comment: Can you post your WinVC code? Im guessing you have some view in there that's not clear. Make sure all views have their background color set to clear.

Comment: Not much there as I have removed everything to solve this first issue. Post updated with also the setup in IB

Comment: pretty sure that's why. the view that comes with the view controller needs to be set to clear. giving it a try myself, but you might beat me to it, as i have to make a test project =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with the following solution :

- Set VCWin Presentation parameter to "Over full
  screen"
- Set VCWin size to the same size as the VC it goes over
- Set the background color of the SKView in VCWin to "Clear Color"
- The image used as background in the SKView has to have alpha where transparency is wanted (the corners in my case)
- Set the SKView size to the size of the image used as background
- Create a ShapeNode with color/transparency correctly set-up and put it on top of the SKScene which is in the VC behind VCWin to do the dim effect

Then I have the wanted result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your frame is fine - It's probably because your `UIViewController` contains a view object, that has a white background. In your `WinVC` class's `viewDidLoad`, do this:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIcolor.clearColor()
```

Comment: It was already the case through the IB setups (see update in post). view and image have background set to clear. And when I use Alpha, the whole content of the WinVC is dimmed.